# can't have 2 ng-click on the same page

Tags: javascript

There are two ng-controller which have one ng-click for each.

If I set the script for two ng-click as the following code, those two buttons will not work. But if I only set the script for either one ng-click, the button works.

How can I solve it?

```
<body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="loginController">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <form class="login" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" ng-model="password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="login()" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="registerController">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <form class="register" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" ng-model="emailR">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Enter password" ng-model="pwdR">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" ng-model="nameR">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" ng-click="register()" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script>
        var api = ""

        angular.module("myapp", []).controller("loginController", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.login = function(){
                if(!isEmpty($scope.email) || !isEmpty($scope.password)){
                    var loginInfo = api + "login/" + $scope.email + "/" + $scope.password;
                    var responsePromise = $http.get(loginInfo);
                    responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        var msg = data.result;
                        alert(msg);
                        top.location.reload();
                    });
                    responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert("AJAX fail!");
                    }); 
                }
            }
        });

        angular.module("myapp", []).controller("registerController", function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.register = function(){
                if(!isEmpty($scope.emailR) || !isEmpty($scope.pwdR || !isEmpty($scope.nameR))){
                    var registerInfo = api + "register/" + $scope.emailR + "/" + $scope.pwdR + "/" + $scope.nameR;                      alert(registerInfo);
                    var responsePromise = $http.get(registerInfo);
                    responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        var msg = data.result;
                        alert(msg);
                    });
                    responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        alert("AJAX fail!");
                    }); 
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You may want to name your controller with an alias and then use this alias as a prefix when calling the method on the ng-click(). Example: ng-controller="loginController as ctrl" and then ng-click="ctrl.login()" Of course change the alias name to whatever suits better. Usually the name of the controller in singular and lower case. This way you can even have nested controllers. And on the definition of the method on the controller use: this.login, instead of $scope.login

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using button type submit with different `<form>` elements you can do something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="loginController">
    <form name="loginForm" data-ng-submit="login()">
         <button type="submit">Submit Form 1</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div ng-controller="registerController"> 
    <form name="registerForm" data-ng-submit="register()">
        <button type="submit">Submit Form 2</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

The ng-submit automatically recognises the submit button and you can write a function in your two controllers as:

```
 <script>
    var api = ""

    angular.module("myapp", []).controller("loginController", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.login = function(){
            if(!isEmpty($scope.email) || !isEmpty($scope.password)){
                var loginInfo = api + "login/" + $scope.email + "/" + $scope.password;
                var responsePromise = $http.get(loginInfo);
                responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    var msg = data.result;
                    alert(msg);
                    top.location.reload();
                });
                responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("AJAX fail!");
                }); 
            }
        }
    });

    angular.module("myapp", []).controller("registerController", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.register = function(){
            if(!isEmpty($scope.emailR) || !isEmpty($scope.pwdR || !isEmpty($scope.nameR))){
                var registerInfo = api + "register/" + $scope.emailR + "/" + $scope.pwdR + "/" + $scope.nameR;                      alert(registerInfo);
                var responsePromise = $http.get(registerInfo);
                responsePromise.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    var msg = data.result;
                    alert(msg);
                });
                responsePromise.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    alert("AJAX fail!");
                }); 
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: ughhh..still not work. I think it is not the problem of ng-submit.

Comment: no error got. But it is solved by my friend. Thanks anyway.